# Lo que necesito en si es que cuando el personaje colisione con la puerta salte al siguiente nivel, como hago esto?

Tags: c++, sfml

Este es uno de los niveles, está declarado como global.

```
String Capitulo_1[] = {
"OTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTO",
"P                                 p",
"P                                 p",
"P                                 p",
"P                                 p",
"P                                 p",
"P                                 p",
"P                                 p",
"P                                 p",
"P                                 p",
"P                                 p",
"P                                 p",
"OBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBO",
};
```

Así dibujo el nivel:

```
void Capitulo_1(Sprite &tile, RenderWindow &window)
{
 for(unsigned int i=0; i<Alto_map; i++)
    for(unsigned int j=0; j<Ancho_map; j++){
if(TileMap[i][j]=='B') tile.setTextureRect(IntRect(  0, 0, 32, 32));//piso
if(TileMap[i][j]=='T') tile.setTextureRect(IntRect( 32, 0, 32, 32));//techo
if(TileMap[i][j]=='O') tile.setTextureRect(IntRect( 64, 0, 32, 32));//simiento
if(TileMap[i][j]=='s') tile.setTextureRect(IntRect( 96, 0, 32, 32));//punta izq
if(TileMap[i][j]=='d') tile.setTextureRect(IntRect(128, 0, 32, 32));//punta der
if(TileMap[i][j]=='p') tile.setTextureRect(IntRect(224, 0, 32, 32));//pared der
if(TileMap[i][j]=='P') tile.setTextureRect(IntRect(256, 0, 32, 32));//pared izq
if(TileMap[i][j]=='Z') tile.setTextureRect(IntRect(32, 0, 32, 32));//ENERGIA Fal
if(TileMap[i][j]=='z') tile.setTextureRect(IntRect(591, 0, 12, 15));//ENERGIA
if(TileMap[i][j]=='D') tile.setTextureRect(IntRect(507, 207, 71, 78));//PUERTA 
if(TileMap[i][j]==' ' || TileMap[i][j]=='X') continue;

         tile.setPosition(j*32 - offsetX, i*32 - offsetY);
         window.draw(tile);
       }
}
```

Esta es la función que carga los niveles:

```
void cargarCapitulo(Image &i, RenderWindow &window, int Numero_del_Capitulo)
{
    int cap = Numero_del_Capitulo;
    Sprite tile;
    Texture txt;
    txt.loadFromImage(i);
    tile.setTexture(txt);

    switch (cap)
     {
        case 1: Capitulo_1(tile, window); break;
        case 2: Capitulo_Boss(tile, window); break;

        case 3: Capitulo_2(tile, window); break;
        case 4: Capitulo_Boss(tile, window); break;

        case 5: Capitulo_3(tile, window); break;
        case 6: Capitulo_Boss(tile, window); break;

        case 7: Capitulo_4(tile, window); break;
        case 8: Capitulo_Boss(tile, window); break;

        case 9: Capitulo_5(tile, window); break;
        case 10: Capitulo_Boss(tile, window); break;

        case 11: Capitulo_6(tile, window); break;
        case 12: Capitulo_Boss(tile, window); break;

        //default : fin_del_juego(); break;
     }
}
```

Así lo llamo en `main`:

```
int main(){
    cargarCapitulo(t, w, l);
}
```

Así localizo al personaje:

```
personaje.rect.left o personaje.spt.getPosition().y
```

Clase del `Personaje`:

```
PERSONAJE::PERSONAJE(Image &i, int lvl)
{
    t.loadFromImage(i);
    spt.setTexture(t);

    cap = lvl;
    Cargar_Personaje();

    vida = true; poder = 3; dispara = 0; dx = dy = 0.1; cframe = 0;
}

void PERSONAJE::Cargar_Personaje()
{
    switch (cap)
     {
        case 1:  rect = FloatRect(1*32, 11*32, 25, 32); break;
        case 2:  rect = FloatRect(1*32, 11*32, 25, 32); break;
        case 3:  rect = FloatRect(1*32, 10*32, 25, 32); break;
        case 4:  rect = FloatRect(1*32, 11*32, 25, 32); break;
        case 5:  rect = FloatRect(1*32, 11*32, 25, 32); break;
        case 6:  rect = FloatRect(1*32, 11*32, 25, 32); break;
        case 7:  rect = FloatRect(1*32,  9*32, 25, 32); break;
        case 8:  rect = FloatRect(1*32, 11*32, 25, 32); break;
        case 9:  rect = FloatRect(1*32, 11*32, 25, 32); break;
        case 10: rect = FloatRect(1*32, 11*32, 25, 32); break;
        case 11: rect = FloatRect(1*32, 11*32, 25, 32); break;
        case 12: rect = FloatRect(1*32, 11*32, 25, 32); break;
     }
}

void PERSONAJE::control()
{
    if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Left)) {stado = left; dx = -0.1; }
    if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Right)) {stado = right; dx = 0.1; }
    if(Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Z)) if(sTierra) {dy = -0.36; sTierra = false;}
    if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::X)) { dispara = true; }
}

void PERSONAJE::actualizar(float tiempo)
{
     if(vida) control();
    //vida = p;
    rect.left += dx * tiempo;
    Colision(0);

    if(!sTierra) dy = dy + 0.0005 * tiempo;
    rect.top += dy*tiempo;
    sTierra = false;
    Colision(1);

    cframe += 0.005*tiempo;
    if(cframe > 3) cframe -=3;

    if(dx>0) spt.setTextureRect(IntRect(0+32*int(cframe), 232, 32, 32));
    if(dx<0) spt.setTextureRect(IntRect(5+32*int(cframe), 200, 32, 32));

    if (!vida) spt.setTextureRect(IntRect(0, 0, 1, 1));
    spt.setPosition(rect.left - offsetX, rect.top - offsetY);

    dx = 0;
}

void PERSONAJE::Colision(int dir)
{
   if(cap == 1)
   {
    for (int i = rect.top/32 ; i<(rect.top+rect.height)/32; i++)
        for (int j = rect.left/32; j<(rect.left+rect.width)/32; j++)
        {
            if(TileMap[i][j]=='B' || TileMap[i][j]=='P' || TileMap[i][j]=='p' || TileMap[i][j]=='O' ||
           TileMap[i][j]=='T' || TileMap[i][j]=='s' || TileMap[i][j]=='d' || TileMap[i][j]=='Z' || TileMap[i][j]=='D')
            {

            if ((dx>0) && (dir==0)) rect.left =  j*32 -  rect.width;
            if ((dx<0) && (dir==0)) rect.left =  j*32 + 32;
            if ((dy>0) && (dir==1))  { rect.top =   i*32 -  rect.height;  dy=0;   sTierra=true; }
            if ((dy<0) && (dir==1))  { rect.top = i*32 + 32;   dy=0;}
            }
        }
    }
```

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Como sabes donde está el personaje?

Comment: El código facilitado no ayuda en nada a deducir cuál es tu problema y cómo solucionarlo. ¿Qué código de detección de colisiones usas? ¿Qué código de carga/descarga de niveles usas? ¿Qué sistema de coordenadas usas?

Comment: Otra pregunta, en el título dices "**Necesito** hacer una clase o una función para **dibujar el nivel en pantalla**" y en el cuerpo dices "Lo que **necesito** en si es que **cuando el personaje colisione con la puerta salte al siguiente nivel**". ¿Cuál es la pregunta?

Comment: Falta el codigo del personaje, aparte en tu nivel uno no tienes puertas (D)

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Lo que necesito en si es que cuando el personaje colisione con la puerta salte al siguiente nivel, como hago esto ?

Comment: @jasilva Ese nivel es un ejemplo, por eso no tiene puerta.

Comment: @ZeroMyD tu duda no puede ser respondida de una manera directa ni sencilla, tu código tiene tantas interdependencias incorrectas que requeriría un rediseño completo para conseguir lo que buscas. Si quieres, podemos hablar de ello en un chat.

Comment: PaperBirdMaster ok, gracias por tomarte tu tiempo para ayudarme. En que chat podriamos hablar?

Answer (score 0):

Viendo el método `PERSONAJE::Colision`, entiendo que puedes saber si el personaje colisiona con la puerta si `TileMap[i][j]=='D'` , entonces, en ese mismo método después de comprobar colisión (o creando otro método solo para puertas), puedes indicar que si colisiona con una puerta cambie de nivel, algo parecido a `if(TileMap[i][j]=='D') cargarCapitulo(loQueSea);`.